# Input and output from parallel port

Tags: c#, windows, parallel-port

I basically want to get the parallel port input & want to give the output simultaneously in the c#.net without using the inpout32.dll. Can any one guide me how to control the parallel port in c# without inpout32.dll. And how to get input and give output parallely?? I am using data pins for the output and control and status pins for the input, in the window OS.

Comment: Why exactly can't you use the DLL you mention?

Comment: Agreed, use the DLL given to you or stop using Windows and go get your soldering iron.

Comment: I tagged it as homework because the OP stated it was.

Comment: Be careful with that stuff - the parallel port's expected voltage is very small and very sensitive. (I'm talking about the hardware part of the issue here).

I made this with C a dozen or so years ago, but that was before the OSes really clamped down on hardware IOs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until there's a reason given why it can't work, just use the facilities provided to you by the platform (the DLL and so forth).

Comment: Sir basically its the requirment of our project, that built your own function instead of using the dll files

Comment: Oh, so it's a homework assignment.  You should say so in the original post.

Comment: The assignment is to develop a replacement for inpout32.dll ?  That's a nasty little problem - What's the course ? Oh, and google windows inpout32.dll for LOTS of hints to accomplish that task.